# sql UPDATE error?

Tags: php, sql

I've followed all the mySQL tutorials correctly but it still won't update the values in my table, can someone please help me?, these are my values below:

```
$editid = $_GET['id'];
$newtitle = $_POST['title'];
$newsneak = $_POST['sneak'];
$newbody = $_POST['body'];

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("Couldn't Connect. ");
mysql_select_db("dr") or die ("Couldn't Find DB.");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$editid");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows=!0)
{
$querytitle = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET title=$newtitle WHERE id=$editid");
$querysneak = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET summary=$newsneak WHERE id=$editid");
$querybody  = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET body=$newbody WHERE id=$editid");
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Comment: you should also merge the three update query into one.

Answer (score 3):

On your select (add myql_error to check error):

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$editid'");
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   }
```

On your update:

```
$querytitle = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET title='$newtitle' WHERE id='$editid'");
$querysneak = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET summary=$newsneak WHERE id='$editid'");
$querybody  = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET body='$newbody' WHERE id='$editid'");
```

use single quote around input data also use `mysql_real_escape_string();` avoid sql injection.

[PHP mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

---

As per @Tchalvak suggestion to include mention of binding, these are more updated tools against SQL Injections plus better optimization, but keep in mind PDO and MySQLi are supported if you have PHP 5+:

[PHP PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

and

[PHP MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: as far as i know, i don't think php's mysql supports binding param (is this what you were referring to?). it would be either mysqli or PDO. which requires poster to have php5+.  poster uses mysql.  Please correct me for further wrong.  thanks

Comment: I was indeed referring to using PDO binding, which at least merits mention, `mysql_real_escape_string` is indeed better than nothing, but not a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) function to see what error your query returns.

As integration pointed out by [Jeremy Conley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649120/jeremy-conley), pay attention to don't let the `mysql_error` function output get published in your production HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Can I add as well once you finish debugging to please remove any mysql_error() output? This is awesome info for attackers since it reveals database details. Either log it or don't show errors...adds a little extra security.